# I want to "intercept" a delete button press

Tags: javascript

I would like to "intercept" a delete button press - I believe this is possible with Javascript? I don't know the exact terminology.

Here's my code:

```
<button type="submit" name="del" value=' . stripslashes($cultrow["cult_id"]) . '>Del</button></td>
```

I would like to intercept any and all presses of this button with the name "del". The value will, as you can see, change.

How would I go about this? I want to throw up a dialogue asking the user for confirmation, which I believe can be done using the confirm() function.

Thank you for your assistance all!

Answer (score 0):

You could place the JavaScript inline, and while not my preferred method of doing it, works and reduces the amount of code needed.

```
<button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" type="submit" name="del" value=' . stripslashes($cultrow["cult_id"]) . '>Del</button></td>
```

Comment: Ah, did not know that onclick would work for this. Thought that that only worked for buttons that were not submit buttons. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Without any JavaScript framework, the simplest thing would be to add an `onclick` attribute

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
```

Note that your PHP code should read

```
<button type="submit" name="del" value="' . htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($cultrow["cult_id"])) . '">Del</button>
```

To avoid cross-site scripting vulnerabilities you must always HTML-escape any data you output to the page. You are also missing the double quotes at the value attribute.