# Intercept delete button press - cancelling in confirmation does nothing

Tags: javascript

I asked a similar question recently:

[I want to "intercept" a delete button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010830/i-want-to-intercept-a-delete-button-press)

Basically I am trying to intercept a delete button press. I can get a confirmation using `confirm("Are you sure?")` in an `onclick=`, however, no matter what I choose, ok or cancel, it still proceeds to delete the item I clicked delete on.

How do I prevent this?

My code looks like this:

```
'<td><button type="submit" name="del" onclick="confirm(\'Are you sure?\')" value=' . stripslashes($servrow["serv_id"]) . '>Del</button></td>
```

How do I make it so that clicking cancel doesn't delete the item!

(If anyone needs me to convert the interspersed PHP into just HTML, let me know, I'd be happy to, to increase understanding of my problem)

Answer (score 0):

The confirm dialog returns a value, depending on which button was clicked ('Ok' or 'Cancel').

At the moment, the confirm dialog is showing, and regardless of which button is clicked, the `submit` action of the form is completed (which I'm assuming goes ahead to delete the item).

You should put the `onclick` functionality into a function, so:

```
<button type="submit" name="del" onclick="return confirmDelete();" value=' . stripslashes($servrow["serv_id"]) . '>Del</button>
```

The `confirmDelete()` function would look something like:

```
var c = confirm('Are you sure?');
if(c==true) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Returning true will allow the `submit` action to complete. Returning `false` will stop it from completing (again, I'm assuming the delete is processed only when the form is submitted).

Comment: Ok, I was figuring I might have to write a function for this. Was just wondering if there was an easier way. Thanks!

Comment: Hrm, Netbeans gives me "invalid return" here

Comment: I am an idiot, completely forgot to wrap the logic in a function.

Comment: Also, this did not work. It still deletes when clicked, after prompting for a confirmation.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to add return to the onClick - sorry! Try `onclick="return confirmDelete();"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><button type="submit" name="del" onclick="if !confirm(\'Are you sure?\') return false;" value=' . stripslashes($servrow["serv_id"]) . '>Del</button>
```